# What "tools" are available in Python standard library

Tags: python

I'm currently aware of two tools:

1. base64 encoder/decoder:

   `python -m base64 -e <input`
   `python -m base64 -d <input`
2. json validator and pretty printer

   `python -m json.tool <input`

where input can be stdin or file.

I'm curious if there are other tools exposed by SPL that work in similar fashion?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Many.

```
$ grep "if __name__ == '__main__':" /usr/lib64/python2.7/* | wc -l
55
```

Not all work as a filter though, so examine the module in question before running.

Comment: +1 awesome. Eye-opening.

Comment: Yes, that seems like a reasonable pattern to look for. I thought that there is maybe a web page describing these tools, but couldn't find one. This is closest as it gets I guess, while still being on a simple side. Thanks

Comment: Is there a Mac OS X equivalent for this?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: BSD wc shouldn't be *that* much different...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: `/usr/lib64` doesn't exist; it's not `wc`

Comment: Replace `/usr/lib64` with whatever passes for OS X's Python install location (hint: `print aifc.__file__`), and I'm surprised it doesn't have `wc` seeing as how it has the man page.

Comment: `grep "if __name__ == '__main__':" \`python -c 'import os; print os.path.dirname(os.__file__)'\`/* | wc -l`. And yes, OS X has `wc`.

Comment: Dont forget to check for the other quote style, and use recursive grep -- there are more goodies, e.g. calandar.py:  `grep -rs "if __name__ == [\'\"]__main__[\'\"]:" /usr/lib/python2.7`

Answer (score 109):

Not a complete list...

### Encoding

Base64 en/decoding:

```
python -m base64 -d [file]
python -m base64 -e [file]
```

ROT-13 en/decoder:

```
python -m encodings.rot_13
```

Macintosh BinHex:

```
# binhex <file> to <file>.hqx, and unbinhex <file>.hqx to <file>.viahqx
python -m binhex <file>
```

UUencode/decode:

```
python -m uu [infile [outfile]] # encode
python -m uu -d [infile [outfile]] # decode
```

MIME quoted-printable en/decoding:

```
python -m mimify -e [infile [outfile]] # encode
python -m mimify -d [infile [outfile]] # decode
```

Quoted-printable en/decoding:

```
python -m quopri [file] # encode
python -m quopri -d [file] # decode
```

### Compression

GZip:

```
python -m gzip [file] # compress
python -m gzip -d [file] # decompress
```

Zipfile extraction, etc.:

```
python -m zipfile -l <file> # list
python -m zipfile -t <file> # test
python -m zipfile -e <file> <dir> # extract
python -m zipfile -c <file> sources... # create
```

### Internet

HTTP servers:

```
python -m BaseHTTPServer
python -m CGIHTTPServer
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Simple FTP client:

```
python -m ftplib host [-l<dir-to-list>] [-d<dir-to-cwd>] [-p] [file-to-retrieve]
```

HTML Text extraction:

```
python -m htmllib <file>
```

JSON Validator and pretty-printer:

```
python -m json.tool [infile [outfile]]
```

List POP3 mailbox:

```
python -m poplib <server> <username> <password>
```

SMTP server:

```
python -m smtpd
```

Send a mail message (to localhost):

```
python -m smtplib
```

Telnet client:

```
python -m telnetlib [host [port]]
```

MIME type/extension database:

```
python -m mimetypes file.ext # print type for filename
python -m mimetypes -e mime/type # print extension for type
```

Open webbrowser:

```
python -m webbrowser -n <url> # new window
python -m webbrowser -t <url> # new tab
```

[Antigravity](http://xkcd.com/353/):

```
python -m antigravity
```

### Python

Pure-Python REPL:

```
python -m code
```

Python bytecode batch compiler:

```
python -m compileall
```

Python code profiler:

```
python -m cProfile <script>
python -m profile <script>
python -m pstats <filename> # print profiling statistics
```

Python doctest executor:

```
python -m doctest <script>
```

Python benchmark:

```
python -m test.pystone [iterations]
python -m hotshot.stones
```

Python interactive debugger:

```
python -m pdb
```

Extract Python classes and methods from a module:

```
python -m pyclbr <script>
```

Python documentation browser:

```
python -m pydoc <topic>
python -m pydoc -g # graphical browser
python -m pydoc -p <port> # start HTTP docs server on port
```

Python snippet timer:

```
python -m timeit
```

### Misc

Calendar (like `cal`, but can do HTML and various fancy formatting stuff):

```
python -m calendar
```

Directory comparer:

```
python -m filecmp [-r] dir1 dir2 # -r for recursive directory compare
```

Paragraph formatting:

```
python -m formatter [file]
```

Show current platform (like `uname` but simpler):

```
python -m platform
```

Comment: Thanks for explicitly showing examples, and adding description. It's a very nice reference to have.

Comment: While many of these are convenient - please don't start using these in lieu of real applications/commands. I am unhappy whenever someone shells out to a command, I would hate to start seeing `python -m gzip -d file` instead of `gunzip file` in a bash script.

Comment: @NathanAdams It's years later, but I just found this. What reason other than speed is there to use the native tools instead of the python scripts? The python scripts seem like they would be more portable and more widely installed.

Comment: I would argue gunzip is more standard than Python (it's part of the GNU library of programs) so it's very unlikely they are going to change including command line parameters. Python developers on the other hand seem to play fast and loose with releases and like to change things (for good or bad). The gzip Python library probably won't change - but I personally would rather not have to depend on it (see urllib). I'm not against using Python but using gunzip which was written in C just seems more logical than spinning up the entire Python interpreter into memory.

Answer (score 12):

Also, there is:

```
python -m this
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also -m compatible packages on the Cheeseshop. Try "e" or "oo" :-)