# How to consume webservice using CURL command?

Tags: linux, web-services, unix, ubuntu, geocoding

I am trying to consume webservices using unix `CURL` command but somehow I am getting request denied error.

I am trying to consume this webservice url-

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=95112&destinations=94000&mode=bicycling&sensor=false

I am able to open the above url in the browser and I am able to see the contents.

Now I am trying to consume the same webservice using CURL command but it's not working for me.

I am trying something like this-

`curl http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=95050&destinations=94087&mode=bicycling&sensor=false`

Is there anything wrong I am doing? I need to extract `text portion of distance object`.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` character is special in the shell; so the command is executing fine, just being sent to the background. These numbers `[1] 4373
[2] 4374
[3] 4375` are the process id's that are sent to the background. You can tell later on that they are finished with `[1]   Done`. To avoid this, you should quote the URL.

You also need to supply the `-o` option to curl; because I assume you are trying to save the json file to be processed later:

```
curl -o bikes.json "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...."
```

You can also use `wget` which is designed especially for this:

```
wget "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...." -O bikes.json
```

Or, my personal favorite [`httpie`](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie):

```
http "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api..." > bikes.json
```

To parse json at the shell, you can use a tool like [`jsawk`](https://github.com/micha/jsawk). However, I prefer the much more simpler:

`curl -s "http://www.example.com/..." | python -mjson.tool | grep "distance"`

Comment: :Thanks Burhan for the suggestion. Now its working fine. Any idea if I can get the text portion of distance object using curl or some more processing directly? Or what's the easiest way to get that?

Comment: what is mjson.tool here? pardon my ignorance

Comment: `-m` is an arugment to python and `json` is a library (the `.tool` is a way to use the functionality of the library directly). There is a nicely compiled [list of these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545001/what-tools-are-available-in-python-standard-library) here at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Curl just work for see and test data in a Server through an URL.
To consume the webservice itself you need a programming language which parse the content JSON (or other) in the response of an HTTP Request like the url you paste here to a type (of the language, like Arrays, Dicts, or something else) that can be worked.